# How to install specific SDK (I need 6.0.300)

Tags: .net, sdk, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running WSL-Ubuntu 20.04 on windows and need to have dotnet 6.0.300.

I have 5.0.480 and 6.0.400 installed, but I can't figure out how to get the specific one (dotnet 6.0.300).

Answer (score 1):

Only certain releases are available via package manager install.  If you need another release, follow the [Manual Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#manual-install) instructions:

- Find your desired release on the [6.0 downloads](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0) page
- Follow the link to the [6.0.3 SDK x64 Linux download](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/thank-you/sdk-6.0.300-linux-x64-binaries).
- Abort the download (easier to do it inside WSL)
- Copy the direct download link to the clipboard
- In Ubuntu/WSL:

  ```
  cd ~
  wget <copied_url>
  mkdir -p ~/.local/lib/dotnet-6.0.3
  cd ~/.local/lib/dotnet-6.0.3
  tar xvzf ~/dotnet-sdk-6.0.303-linux-x64.tar.gz
  # Adjust above if filename is different
  export DOTNET_ROOT="$HOME/.local/lib/dotnet-6.0.3"
  export PATH="${DOTNET_ROOT}:${PATH}"

  # Check the above with:
  echo $PATH
  echo $DOTNET_ROOT

  dotnet --info
  ```

  Since you have multiple releases installed, I'm assuming you don't want to add the exports to your startup, and would rather run them manually when you want that particular version.  But if you do want it to be the default, of course, simply add the exports to your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent).

Comment: Sorry for total noob question (I´m new to programming). 
On these lines of code: 
"export DOTNET_ROOT="$HOME/.local/lib/dotnet-6.0.3" and "export PATH="${DOTNET_ROOT}:${PATH}"
Am I supposed to fill in the PATH, DOTNET_ROOT etc with my own local directories?

Comment: @EricRosén No worries - And no -- It's actually the opposite.  The variables, like  `${DOTNET_ROOT}` and `${PATH}` should be exactly as they are written.  The only thing that you would need to change is the directory itself, if it's different.  So replace `$HOME/.local/lib/dotnet-6.0.3` with whatever directory you placed the files in.  Then the other variable assignments will pick it up.

Comment: Should these last two export commands go together or on separate rows? If I run only the first one "export DOTNET_ROOT="$HOME/.local/lib/dotnet-6.0.3" I assume the path should follow since Ubuntu gives me a >, indicating the command isn't complete. Should the next command: "export PATH="${DOTNET_ROOT}:${PATH}" be written out in full, or do I start at the dollar sign? Should the "" be included? Can't seem to get it right :(  My command prompt says: eric_rosen@MSI:~/.local/lib/dotnet-6.0.3$

Comment: @EricRosén Ack - Yes, that's a typo on my part that's causing the `>` you are seeing.  It's just missing the closing quote.  Edited the answer.  Apologies!